# My question is about solving equation

Tags: equation-solving

Respected Sir, I am trying to get an equation of Qk in terms of Qp and k, for which
`G[Q_] = 1/40 (x)^(1/5)*1/(12*Q^(1/5) (1 + Q)^(6/5)) (-32 (10125/(125 x)) Log[Q (1 + Q)^6] + 15 (1 + Q) (-4 + 20 Q -15 Q (1 + Q) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 8/5, 9/5, -Q])); Solve[G[Qk] - G[Qp] == y, Qk, Reals]`

But the output is "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help."
Please help me out. I have tried everything.

Comment: (1) The message I get is "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." (2)  *Mathematica* has limited ability to solve transcendental equations with parameters. (I rather think mathematics at large has trouble with them.)  (3) You can use `FindRoot` if you give numerical values to the parameters (`x`, `y`, `Qp`?). (4) You could also use `InverseFunction`, but I usually avoid it and use `FindRoot`.

Comment: Dear Michael E2, Thanks for your reply, values of x and Qp are 3.03*10^10 and 10^-1 respectively, but i have to get Qk as a function of y atleast. Any other way to solve the equation?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that `Solve` or `NSolve` are able to handle this equation even with the values you provided in the comments.

Best thing I was able to produce was a single particular solution using `FindInstance`:

```
G[Q_] := 1/40 (x)^(1/5)*1/(12*Q^(1/5) (1 + Q)^(6/5)) (-32 (10125/(125 x)) Log[Q (1 + Q)^6] + 15 (1 + Q) (-4 + 20 Q -15 Q (1 + Q) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 8/5, 9/5, -Q]));
vars = {Qk,Qp,x,y}
vals = {Qp->(303/100)*10^10, x->10^-1}
eqn = FullSimplify[(G[Qk] - G[Qp] == y)/.vals]
inst = FindInstance[eqn, vars, Reals]
Print[inst]
Print[N[inst]]
```

gives

```
{{Qk -> 27, Qp -> -1/2, x -> -9/5, y -> (869780104257411228000947380*6^(2/5)*35^(4/5) - 224932050005938799999951*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5) + 5111580836587398075005567625000000*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 8/5, 9/5, -30300000000] - 18401691011714633070020043450*6^(2/5)*35^(4/5)*Hypergeometric2F1[1, 8/5, 9/5, -27] + 169344*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[2] + 21168*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[3] + 169344*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[5] + 21168*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[101] + 127008*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[2789] + 127008*10^(1/5)*9180900000303^(4/5)*Log[10864109] - 100145257206610248000109080*6^(2/5)*35^(4/5)*Log[13011038208])/10904705784719782560011877600}}
```

or numerically:

```
{{Qk -> 27., Qp -> -0.5, x -> -1.8, y -> -7.60110441041372}}
```

**Edit:**

A little more insight can be gained by plotting `y` for particular choices of `Qk`.

If we define

```
nsol[n_] := NSolve[eqn&&Qk==n, vars, Reals]
```

it gives us the solution from `FindInstance` by calling

```
nsol[27]

{{Qk->27., y->-7.6011}}
```

We can now plot `nsol`:

```
Plot[(y/.nsol[n])//First,{n,0,30}]
```

[image]